# Ansible: Backing up variable value doesn't work as expected

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Attempting to save a variable's value for backup before modifying it doesn't work.

I have the following inventory file (note the custom ansible_port and user):

```
all:
    hosts:
            test:
                    ansible_port: 11111
                    ansible_user: user_foo
                    ansible_host: 192.168.56.101
```

And I have the following playbook:

```
- name: Test
  hosts: test
  vars:
          backup_ansible_port: "{{ ansible_port }}"
          backup_ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
          ansible_port: "{{ tmp_port }}"
          ansible_user: root
  tasks:
          - name: foo
            debug:
                    msg: 
                    - "{{ backup_ansible_port }}"
                    - "{{ backup_ansible_user }}"
                    - "{{ ansible_port }}"
                    - "{{ ansible_user }}"
```

Running the following command:

> ansible-playbook bootstrap_ssh.yml --ask-pass -e 'target=test tmp_port=22'

The output is the following:

```
...
TASK [foo] *********************************
  ok: [test] => {
      "msg": [
          "22", 
          "root", 
          "22", 
          "root"
      ]
  }
...
```

> Expected output:

```
...
TASK [foo] *********************************
  ok: [test] => {
      "msg": [
          "11111", 
          "user_foo", 
          "22", 
          "root"
      ]
  }
...
```

Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a totally expected result. You define the same variables in different places and ansible applies its [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

First of all, remember that variables passed as extra vars always win: you can never change them in any other place or during the run (i.e. `set_fact`).

Now let's decompose what happens. The schema is basically the same for all vars where you don't get the expected result. I'll only give the example for `backup_ansible_port`. You can follow the spaghetti yourself for the others once you got it.

When you hit the debug task to display `"{{ backup_ansible_port }}"`

1. The first jinja2 template pass finds it should be an expansion of `ansible_port` as defined in your play vars.
2. `ansible_port` is defined with value "11111" directly in your inventory as a host var (see #8 in above precedence doc) **But** it is also defined as an expansion of `tmp_port` in your play vars (see #12 in above precedence doc). Higher precedence wins, so the second jinja2 template pass finds it should expand `tmp_port`
3. `tmp_port` has value "22" in your extra vars which will be the final value returned.